# Difficulty understanding the Python data model and how built-in functions map to special methods

Tags: python

I have a Java background and am studying [Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). Specifically, I am curious about how and when special methods (e.g. `__add__`) get called.

It seems like the Python interpreter may execute these special methods when it encounters certain built-in functions. To take an example from the book "Fluent Python", if you have a class like the following `FrenchDeck`...

```
import collections

Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])

class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits
                                        for rank in self.ranks]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)

    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self._cards[position]
```

then `__getitem__` will get called when the Python interpreter encounters things like `for card in FrenchDeck()` or `FrenchDeck()[11]`.

To me, this seems expressive but also extremely vague. How do I determine what built-in functions will call my special methods? There seems to be some implicit mention of mappings between built-ins and special methods in statements of the [Python Data Model section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) like

> It is recommended that both mappings and sequences implement the `__contains__()` method to allow efficient use of the `in` operator.

But I can't find a clear reference doc with statements like "for user-defined classes, `in` will use `__contains__` if it exists, otherwise it will use `__getitem__`".

Comment: This is a nice, close to exhaustive, reference that maps method names to language constructs: https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the section on `__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) :

> For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`, see [this section in the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details).

From the linked section:

> For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__()` method, `x in y` returns `True` if `y.__contains__(x)` returns a true value, and `False` otherwise.
>
> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is `True` if some value `z`, for which the expression `x is z` or `x == z` is true, is produced while iterating over `y`. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if `in` raised that exception.
>
> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is `True` if and only if there is a non-negative integer index `i` such that `x is y[i]` or `x == y[i]`, and no lower integer index raises the `IndexError` exception. (If any other exception is raised, it is as if `in` raised that exception).

[Here, you can see an example of interpreter C code checking for `__iter__` and `__getitem__` methods](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L6716)